# glXChooseFBConfig fails to select supported config

Tags: linux, opengl, nvidia, glx

I try to select this config with nvidia blob driver on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64):

```
int doubleBufferAttributes[] = {
    GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PBUFFER_BIT,
    GLX_RENDER_TYPE,   GLX_RGBA_BIT,
    GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER,  True,
    GLX_RED_SIZE,      8,
    GLX_GREEN_SIZE,    8,
    GLX_BLUE_SIZE,     8,
    GLX_PBUFFER_WIDTH,  <width>,
    GLX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT,  <height>,
    GLX_DEPTH_SIZE,    24,
    GLX_ALPHA_SIZE,     8,
    None
};
glXChooseFBConfig(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), doubleBufferAttributes, &numReturned);
```

It returns NULL. However I can see in glxinfo that such configuration is supported. Actually I use glXGetFBConfigs myself and I can see the matching fbconfig. One strange thing is that if I do glXGetVisualFromFBConfig for the enumerated matching config and then glXGetConfig(dpy, vis, GLX_ALPHA_SIZE, &v); then I get 0 value, even though I've just verified that FBConfig is for ALPHA=8.

Why this can happen?

P.S. The real problem that I try to debug is that I see no rendered objects with nvidia blob driver, while they are rendered using nouveau driver. I could reproduce it with nouveau if I do glXChooseFBConfig with default values (no specific setup) so I try to play with configs. I try to use the enumerated "valid" config (in glXCreatePbuffer) but still no rendering.

Answer (score 1):

*[Apart from reverse-engineering, to answer why a binary blob did something is an exercise in guessing.  However, a really likely guess is below.]*

According to the [spec](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXChooseFBConfig.xml), `GLX_PBUFFER_WIDTH` and `GLX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT` are not valid attributes to use for selection.  Try removing those.